# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC published to local IIS routing not working HTTP 500 error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have published an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application to my local IIS. The site loads without error, however the routing doesn't work and I am left with a HTTP 500 error when navigating from the home page.

The routing works when I build and load directly from Visual Studio. I am not sure what elements you would need to help me with this, but here is my program.cs.

Help please :). Richard

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RabsoInc.Web.DAL;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("default")));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDomain, DomainRepo>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IItem, ItemRepo>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
app.Run();
```

Comment: Just an update, I think it's database related as when I remove the dependency to the db, the routing works. I will dig into db permissions now.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error.